# Is it possible to add onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave for a checkbox in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I have an `input type="checkbox"` element. I want to display some information while the user hovers over the checkbox. How can I achieve this? Please help.

The following is what I am trying to achieve:

```
<input
   type="checkbox"
   disabled={someBooleanFlag}
   checked={someOtherBooleanFlag}
   onClick={() => this.handleClick()}
   onMouseEnter={() => this.handleMouseEnter()}
 />
```

Comment: I was trying onMouseEnter event for the input element, but then realised, there is no such event for input element.

Comment: Then add it in your question seems reasonable

Comment: Okay. I will edit and add it.

Comment: If the event does not exist for input elements, can't you just wrap that in a div and set the onMouseEnter/onMouseLeave properties on that div?

Comment: I will try this @MichaelH.

Comment: @MichaelH. working fine, but my checkbox is a big square with some CSS, and when I wrap it inside a div, the hover works only when I take the mouse over the corner of the box. I inspected the DOM. The div appears to be sitting in the top left corner. That's why.